# Next Character Check in Java

Tags: java, character

```
String input = "a == b";
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
   char c = input.charAt(i);
   if(c == '='){
      System.out.println("Assignment Operator");
   }
}
```

In the above example if character is `'='` and the next character is also `'='` then print `Comparison Operator`otherwise print  `Assignment Operator`

Comment: Your sample code matches your explanation of your problem very poorly.  Please update your code to reflect your method of reading characters, or update your explanation to match your code.

Comment: Why not `if (input.contains("=="))`?

Comment: Try to understand it's a task  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++){
    if(input.charAt(i) == '=') {
        if(input.charAt(i + 1) == '=') {
            System.out.println("Comparison Operator");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Assignment Operator");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's Working...(Y)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple:

```
if(input.charAt(input.indexOf("=") + 1) == '='){
  System.out.println("Comparison Operator");}else{
System.out.println("Assignment Operator");
}
```

Comment: This will fail if `'='` is the last character.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the strings class `substring` method, or the `charAt` method or you could use the `contains` these all would allow you to do what you want.